# Command to download files from the Amazon S3 to Local System Drive

Tags: amazon-s3, magento-1.8

I have uploaded images from the hosting to the Amazon S3 by using the

```
s3cmd put -r –acl-public –guess-mime-type folder_name s3://abc/path/
```

Now I want to download the images from the Amazon S3 to my local system. Please suggest me the command so that I can download it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [get](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-howto).

```
s3cmd get s3://abc/path/
```

Comment: Manage more details on answer. otherwise add comment on question.